# How can I show my last 3 posts with Django Python

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, post

I try to show my last 3 posts with Django but my three posts doesn't appear on my page. There is my code.
I have no error or anything when I load the page and my other posts apper on my page.
And please be kind it's the first time I use Python and Django =)

### models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(
    blank=True, null=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category')

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

### views

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Category, Post

def category_list(request):
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    return render (request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'categories': categories})

def post_list(request):
posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
latests = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).reverse()[:3]
return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts': posts})
return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'latests': latests})
```

### My urls

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
]
```

### template html (post_list.html)

```
        <div id="container">
        {% for latest in latests %}
        <article class="lastnews">
            <h4>{{ latest.title }}</h4>
            <h5 class="lastestcategory">{{ latest.category }}</h5>
            <p class="bodysmall">{{ latest.text|truncatewords:10 }}</p>
            <div>
                <p class="date">{{ latest.published_date }}</p>
                <p class="showmore"><a href="">Show more</a></p>
            </div>
        </article>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</section>
<section id="posts">
    {% for post in posts %}
    <article class="post">
        <header class="postheader">
            <h4>{{ post.title }}</h4>
            <p class="info">{{ post.category }}, {{ post.published_date }}</p>
        </header>
        <p class="bodyregular">{{ post.text|linebreaksbr }}</p>
        <footer class="postfooter">
            <p class="author">Author: {{ post.author }}</p>
            <p class="showarticle"><a href="">Show article</a></p>
        </footer>
    </article>
    {% endfor %}
</section>
```

Thanks for your help =)

EDIT

I fixed my view in this way

```
def latest_posts(request):
latests = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).reverse()[:3]
return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'latests': latests})
```

but the three posts doesn't appear on my page

Comment: Welcome to SO. Break the habit of using the phrase "It doesnt work". That means nothing to anyone because it doesnt describe what your issue is. You say there is no error. Is anything showing on the page? Are all posts showing on the page?

Comment: Also, you use latests as your variable name and then pass latest as the context. Is that right in your latest_posts view?

Comment: You don't seem to have a URL for latest_posts. How are you calling it?

Comment: And are you sure that the post have an `published_date` set (that it is not null)? And are you sure that those dates are less than `timezone.now()`?

Comment: @DanielRoseman no there is no URL for latest_posts. How should I create the right URL ?

Comment: @Ralf Yes all dates are ok

Comment: @dfundako Thanks for your answer. I changed the error but my posts still not appear.

Comment: I don't understand what you have done, then. How are you expecting a view to work without a URL? Every page you want to visit needs a URL. You have one for post_list, you need one for latest_posts as well if you want to go to it, surely?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Ok I understand that I need to link my view with a URL. But I don't want to show latest_posts on latests_posts.html but on post_list.html. So, should I create the same URL as post_list ? If yes can you help my to create it in the right way ? Thanks for your reply :)

Comment: No that doesn't make sense. If you want to show the latest posts at the same time as the full list of posts, you need to have them in the *same* view, not in separate views, and send both lists to the template.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Ok nice I think I understand. But the only thing that is still not ok for me is how I'm able to call first my three latest posts and then all my posts ? How and where should I write that ?

Comment: Well, again I don't understand unfortunately. Why can't you loop through `latests` first and then `posts`?

Comment: @DanielRoseman That's what I'm trying to do on my template but with my actual code my loop "latests" doesn't add my three posts on my template but "posts" (all the posts) is working and add all the posts.

Comment: Update your question with the new view and the full template.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Here is the new view and the template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found my mistake. I tried to make two return in one def but it doesn't work like that's. I merged the two return in one and it worked ! Thanks every one for helping my :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's your problem

```
def latest_posts(request):
    latests = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).reverse()[:3]
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'latest': latest})
```

You've defined `latests` on line 2 but passed `latest` on line 3.  And then in your template you've reverted to `latests` so you want:

```
def latest_posts(request):
    latests = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).reverse()[:3]
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'latests': latests})
```

Comment: Hello HenryM, thank you so much for your answer ! But nothing change when I reload my page with the modification. Do you have another idea ?